# How to protect your web application when you add an image upload form that's public?

Tags: security, image-uploading

I'm working with a small web app written in aspnet mvc (running on .NET 4). This site is open to the public and we allow anyone to upload an image (jpg/gif/png)

Currently I'm doing what appears to be minimal security like checking during the upload step

1. ensure the file ends with .jpg/.gif/.png
2. verify the actual content type listed for the file coming in is 'image'
3. using param based SQL to (hopefully) avoid basic SQL injection

But I can't help but feel like I'm missing the basics that would prevent an exploit :)

Anything you can suggest that might help reduce risk for a public image upload would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are *many* image-based exploits out there, almost all of them targeting poor image codec implementations. *You* cannot reasonably prevent image exploits from being uploaded unless you're able to re-encode the images in an [sandbox environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29) that will provide a corrupted image little or no opportunity to damage anything on *your* system.